# Как меняются состояния потоков при взаимодействии с объектом синхронизации Событие(Event) в Windows?

Tags: windows, многопоточность, события, синхронизация

Как меняются состояния потоков (для простоты пусть будет два потока) при взаимодействии с объектом синхронизации Событие(Event) в ОС Windows?

Comment: Что вы называете состоянием потока, и что взаимодействием?

Comment: И какой конкретно объект синхронизации вы имеете в виду? Дайте ссылку на MSDN.

Comment: @VladD   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682655(v=vs.85).aspx